# Adding multiple levels of dynamically created tabs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I'm working on a WinForms application in which I have one static TabControl with a tab on which I need to add multiple levels of additional tabs.  The number of these tabs will change depending on the data being loaded to the form.

I can add the first line of dynamic tabs tp the static tab like this for example:

```
TabControl tabControlWafers = new TabControl();
tabControlWafers.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
int numwafers = wafers.Count();
for (int m = 0; m < numwafers; m++)
{
    TabPage tabPage = new TabPage()
    {
        Name = wafers[m]
    };

    tabPage.Text = wafers[m].ToString();
    tabControlWafers.TabPages.Add(tabPage);
}

tabPage1.Controls.Add(tabControlWafers);
```

My problem is that now I need to add another level of dynamically created tabs to each of the pages created above. After creating the next tabs like before:

```
TabControl tabControlStructure = new TabControl();
tabControlStructure.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
int numstruct = structures.Count();
for (int n = 0; n < numstruct; n++)
{
    TabPage tabPagestruct = new TabPage()
    {
        Name = structures[n]
    };

    tabPagestruct.Text = structures[n].ToString();
    tabControlStructure.Controls.Add(tabPagestruct);
}
```

How do I get the tabs created here onto each of the first three tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish what you need by iterating over the `TabPageCollection` in `tabControlWafers.TabPages`, then creating and adding one of your `tabControlStructure` objects at each iteration. See below for an example of how this could be done. Note the example assumes `tabControlWafers` has already been created.

```
foreach (TabPage tp in tabControlWafers.TabPages)
{
    TabControl tabControlStructure = new TabControl()
    {
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    };
    int numstruct = structures.Count();
    for (int i = 0; i < numstruct; i++)
    {
        TabPage tabPagestruct = new TabPage()
        {
            Name = structures[i],
            Text = structures[i]
        };
        tabControlStructure.TabPages.Add(tabPagestruct);
    }
    tp.Controls.Add(tabControlStructure);
}
```

**Edit:**

Below is a generic example of the method by which I would generate the net nested `TabPage` structure. Note that if this were real, production code I would pull the addition of subpages off into its own method (something like `addSubPages(TapPage parent, String[] names`). This is nothing but a simple, paste and run example to give a better picture of what I am describing.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    TabControl tc1 = new TabControl()
    {
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        tc1.TabPages.Add(i.ToString());
    }

    foreach (TabPage tp in tc1.TabPages)
    {
        TabControl tc2 = new TabControl
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            tc2.TabPages.Add(tp.Text + "." + i.ToString());
        }

        tp.Controls.Add(tc2);

        foreach (TabPage tp2 in tc2.TabPages)
        {
            TabControl tc3 = new TabControl
            {
               Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                tc3.TabPages.Add(tp2.Text + "." + i.ToString());
            }
            tp2.Controls.Add(tc3);
        }
    }
    this.Controls.Add(tc1);
}
```

The above example represents the constructor of an otherwise blank form that looks like the following:

[image: Ugly, but gets the point across]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  That makes sense that the structure tabs on each page would require their own tab controls. I tried adding your block in between the numwafers for loop and `tabPage1.Controls.Add(tabControlWafers);` but it still only produced the tabs for the wafers, no structure tabs yet.  I don't see why it wouldn't work correctly...

Comment: In that case, I would ensure `structures` actually contains values at runtime. I just created a stripped down, generic version of what you described and it worked as expected. I will add the generic example to my answer so you can see how I've done it.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks so much for the full example.  I tried updating my actual project with this and it worked in there just as expected.  Much appreciated!

Comment: No problem! If this did in fact work as desired, you can select the green checkmark to accept it. That way, anyone who happens upon this question in the future will know this solution worked.